# What did Ben take a photo of?

Tags: national-treasure-book-of-secrets

What did Ben Gates take a picture of after taking a photo of tablet in [National Treasure: Book of Secrets](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0465234/)? Was it page 47?

Answer (score 0):

It's never explicitly said.  All we know is that he takes a picture of a page in the Book of Secrets.  This would then allow the studio to work this into a third film if they desired, as it's left the story open to continuation.